# Добавление элемента в многомерный массив php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
public $users = [
    '1' => [
        'name' => 'Nick',
        'pass' => 'qwer'
    ],
    '2' => [
        'name' => 'Dany',
        'pass' => 'asdf'
    ]
];
```

Нужно добавить '3' элемент, где 'name' => 'Alek', 'pass' => 'zxcv'.
Нудачние попытки:

```
public function array_insert($users)
    {
        $users[] = '3';
        $users[3] = ['name' => 'Alek', 'pass' => 'zxcv'];

        array_push($users, array('3' => ['name' => 'Alek', 'pass' => 'zxcv']));

        $nusers = [
            '3' => [
                'name' => 'Alek',
                'pass' => 'zxcv'
            ]
        ];

        array_merge($users, $nusers);      
    }
```

Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in E:\DeveloperLibrary\MiniProjectLibrary\PhpProjectCollections\Collections.php on line 27

Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in E:\DeveloperLibrary\MiniProjectLibrary\PhpProjectCollections\Collections.php on line 28

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in E:\DeveloperLibrary\MiniProjectLibrary\PhpProjectCollections\Collections.php on line 30

Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in E:\DeveloperLibrary\MiniProjectLibrary\PhpProjectCollections\Collections.php on line 39

То, что массив не массив я уже понял. Но объявить его по другому я не могу. Но он может быть статическим. Задача состоит в том чтобы была динамическая возможность заносить сюда новые элементы.

Вызов функции:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include 'Collections.php';
        $col = new Collections;
        $col->show($col->users);
        $col->array_insert($col-users);
        $col->show($col->users);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Покажите как Вы вызываете `array_insert`, Вы передаете в нее в качестве параметра не массив

Comment: @Zhukov , вот:  <?php
        include 'Collections.php';
        $col = new Collections;
        $col->show($col->users);
        $col->array_insert($col-users);
        $col->show($col->users);
        ?>

Comment: @Zhukov ,из index.php

Comment: @Anton , вот: <?php include 'Collections.php'; $col = new Collections; $col->show($col->users); $col->array_insert($col-users); $col->show($col->users); ?>

Comment: @Anton ,из index.php

Comment: $col->array_insert($col-users); здесь опечатка как минимум

Comment: Попробуйте создавать массив так : $users=array("1"=>array("name"=> ...), "2"=> ...);

Comment: @axmed2004 ,спасибо я уже разобрался, дело в том что по другому объявить нельзя, т.к. в моем случае объявление прописано разработчиками yii2, мне нужно было дописать функционал регистрации.

Answer (score 1):

Решение в случае статического массива:

```
public static $users = [
    '1' => [
        'name' => 'Nick',
        'pass' => 'qwer'
    ],
    '2' => [
        'name' => 'Dany',
        'pass' => 'asdf'
    ]
];

public function extend_array(){

    array_push(self::$users, ['name' => 'Alek', 'pass' => 'zxcv']);
    print_r(self::$users);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать таким образом:

```
function insert($user = [])
{

    $users['name'] = $user[0];
    $users['pass'] = $user[1];
    return $users;
}

$users = [
    '1' => [
        'name' => 'Nick',
        'pass' => 'qwer'
    ],
    '2' => [
        'name' => 'Dany',
        'pass' => 'asdf'
        ]
    ];

$users[] = insert(['Alex','das']);
```

Вот что показывает var_dump($users);
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function insert()

Comment: покажите ваш код этой реализации

Comment: Что то вы сделали не так

Comment: @Kucenko ,для читабельности тут: https://github.com/Azarchenkov/phpCollections

Comment: @Kucenko ,я пытался по разному вызывать, но всегда эту ошибку выбивает

Comment: Вы же в ООП делаете, метод следует вызывать через this, $this->insert()

Answer (score 0):

Так не будет работать?

```
$users[] = array('3'=> array('name' => 'Alek', 'pass' => 'zxcv'));
```